# do we need query set in CreateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, database

My question is quite straight forward. I'm actually not sure that queryset is required need for CreateAPIView or not.. ?

```
class CreateNotificationAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """This endpoint allows for creation of a notification"""
    queryset = Notification.objects.all() #can we remove it, if we do so, will we face any issue in future ?
    serializer_class = serializers.NotificationSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. The only HTTP method the [**`CreateAPIView`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) offers is the POST method, and it implements this by making a call to the `create` method. The [**`.create(…)`** method is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.13.1/rest_framework/mixins.py#L16-L21):

> ```
> def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
>     serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
>     self.perform_create(serializer)
>     headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
>     return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
> ```

These methods only work with the serializer, or with `self.perform_create` and `self.get_success_headers` that by default only work with the data of the serializer.

If you thus not override the methods of the `CreateAPIView` to use the queryset somehow, you can define a `CreateAPIView` without defining a `queryset` or override `get_queryset`.

Comment: While it works for valid requests, it's possible to trigger a 500 error by making a GET request while setting the header "Accept: text/html". As of Django-rest 3.14 this hits a code path that raises an AssertionError, requiring you to set queryset or override get_queryset. 
I would recommend setting it just to avoid this error in logs.

Answer (score 0):

according to [REST_docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

> queryset - The queryset that should be used for returning objects from
> this view. Typically, you must either set this attribute, or override
> the get_queryset() method. If you are overriding a view method, it is
> important that you call get_queryset() instead of accessing this
> property directly, as queryset will get evaluated once, and those
> results will be cached for all subsequent requests.